# Dependency Hell trying to install GCC on CentOS4

Tags: centos, dependencies, gcc

I have a production CentOS 4.4 box running Virtuozzo VPSes, and I'm trying to install GCC inside one of them so I can install the latest PHP from source. I downloaded gcc and its dependencies from a CentOS mirror and I was able to get some of them installed, but am running into problems with glibc-common:

```
[root@hq gcc]# rpm -i glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 443e1821
        file /usr/bin/gencat from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/getconf from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/getent from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/iconv from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/lddlibc4 from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/locale from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/localedef from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/rpcgen from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/bin/sprof from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/libexec/pt_chown from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/sbin/build-locale-archive from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/sbin/rpcinfo from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/sbin/zdump from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
        file /usr/sbin/zic from install of glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.3.4-2.25
```

So I tried to upgrade instead:

```
[root@hq gcc]# rpm -Uvg glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 443e1821
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc-common = 2.3.4-2.25 is needed by (installed) glibc-2.3.4-2.25.i686
        glibc-common = 2.3.4-2.25 is needed by (installed) glibc-dummy-centos-4-2.3.4-2.25.swsoft.i386
```

It seems like there's a dependency loop where glibc-common depends on glibc, but I can't upgrade glibc until I upgrade glibc-common. I'm also not sure what to do with the glibc-dummy-centos package that Virtuozzo setup. I've searched for solutions but haven't made any progress.

**Update**:

If I try to install them both simultaneously I still got the error about the dummy package:

```
[root@hq gcc]# rpm -Uvh glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm glibc-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm
warning: glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 443e1821
error: Failed dependencies:
        glibc-common = 2.3.4-2.25 is needed by (installed) glibc-dummy-centos-4-2.3.4-2.25.swsoft.i386
```

But I Google'd that and found that that it's safe to remove ([1](http://blog.jphoude.qc.ca/2007/12/18/centos-45-46-update-on-a-virtuozzo-vps/), [2](http://webscholar.net/2009/06/21/yum-glibc-common-error-on-virtuozzo-centos-vps/)) from the RPM database. After doing that I was able to install the remaining RPMs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install both.

```
rpm -Uvh glibc-common-2.3.4-2.43.i386.rpm glibc-...
```

Or better yet, just use yum.

```
yum install gcc
```

Comment: yum isn't available in Virtuozzo VPSes. I'll update the question with the error I get when trying to install them at the same time.

Comment: Yet another reason I won't touch Virtuozzo with a ten-foot cattle prod.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of it either. But half of our servers are running it, so I'm forced to deal with it. Your answer fixed the interdependency problem (I don't know how I missed something that obvious...), and then I found a way to deal with the dummy package. Thanks :)